# Missing write access to /app while npm install using docker in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile, npm-install

Here is my `dockerfile` content, it works fine when I try it locally but it fails on `jenkins` in `npm install` returning this error `Missing write access to /app`.

I'm not sure what is the problem and how can I fix it?

```
USER node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./cypress.json ./cypress.json
COPY --chown=node:node . .
CMD [ "bash" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `/app` directory belongs to **root user**. The user `node` which in the above code snippet has no write permission to this directory. User `node` needs write permission to install node packages (create node_modules directory and package-lock.json file).

So, The solution is too do package installation as **root user** and switch to `USER node` back as in the below code snippet.

```
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./cypress.json ./cypress.json
USER node
COPY --chown=node:node . .
CMD [ "bash" ]
```

This also can be fixed by creating new /app dir and changing its owner at the start as in the below snippet

```
RUN mkdir /app && chown node:node /app
USER node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY ./cypress.json ./cypress.json
COPY . .
RUN npm install
CMD [ "bash" ]
```